# CMD reading text specified in another text file

Tags: batch-file, text, cmd, path

Hi how to read files in another text files.
I have text file with path-names like

**d:\cifs\fslit.txt** with content:

```
d:\cifs\katowice\cifs_list.txt 
d:\cifs\krakow\cifs_list.txt 
d:\cifs\gdansk\cifs_list.txt 
d:\cifs\berlin\cifs_list.txt
```

etc could be hundreds lines of these.

in everyone of these files we have paths like **"d:\cifs\katowice\cifs_list.txt"**:

```
\\katowice\cifs\project\current\box\proj1 
\\katowice\cifs\project\current\box\ide1 
\\katowice\cifs\project\current\box\area_b 
\\katowice\cifs\project\current\box\ide2
```

etc
I would like to put all paths (content) of these files together to one file and remove doublets.

happy with any suggestions ....

Comment: Hi @frodo, welcome to StackOverflow. You can learn [How to format  posts using Markdown or HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) following the link.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). Which operation System are you using?

Comment: This might be a start (for an MS OS) https://superuser.com/questions/111825/a-command-line-or-batch-cmd-to-concatenate-multiple-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option for you.  It does come with some caveats.  If your file lists do not end with a line ending, the last line from the previous file and first line from the next file, will be on the same line in the output file.

```
@echo on

REM Read list of files
(FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("d:\cifs\fslit.txt") DO (
    REM output all files to a single combined file
    TYPE "%%~G"
))>combined.txt
REM Call out to function to remove duplicates from file.
CALL :DEDUPE "combined.txt"
GOTO :EOF

:DEDUPE
:: Remove duplicates from file
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "file=%~1"
set "sorted=%file%.sorted"
set "deduped=%file%.deduped"
::Define a variable containing a linefeed character
set LF=^


::The 2 blank lines above are critical, do not remove
sort "%file%" >"%sorted%"
>"%deduped%" (
  set "prev="
  for /f usebackq^ eol^=^%LF%%LF%^ delims^= %%A in ("%sorted%") do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    if /i "!ln!" neq "!prev!" (
      endlocal
      (echo %%A)
      set "prev=%%A"
    ) else endlocal
  )
)
>nul move /y "%deduped%" "%file%"
del "%sorted%"
GOTO :EOF
```